# how can I return a const vector<unique_ptr<T>>&?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

my code:

```cpp
class Actor;

class ActorManager
{

public:

    template <typename T>
    void makeActors(int count, int types) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Actor, T>::value, "T must be a subclass of Actor");

        m_actors.clear();

        int type = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            type = rand() % types;

            auto actor = make_unique<T>(type);

            m_actors.push_back(move(actor));
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    const vector<unique_ptr<T>>& getActors() const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Actor, T>::value, "T must be a subclass of Actor");
        return static_cast<const vector<unique_ptr<T>>&>(m_actors);
    }

private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Actor>> m_actors;
};
```

the Hero class inherits from the class Actor, ActorManager can be used to manage Hero objects, but I can't access m_actors through public methods getActors().

```
class Hero: public Actor;

for (auto& actor : ActorManager::instance().getActors<Hero>())
{
...
}
```

the compiler report error:

```
error   C2440   "return":
cannot convert from
"const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Actor,std::default_delete<Actor>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Actor,std::default_delete<Actor>>>>"
to 
"const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Hero ,std::default_delete<Hero >>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Hero ,std::default_delete<Hero >>>> &"
```

Comment: why do you waant to make the cast? When the classes are polymorphic it should be unecessary

Comment: This code snippet is roundabout dangerous. what if I have `Dog` instances in `m_actor`? Your code would attempt to treat a Dog as a Hero... The compiler is absolutely right to forbid this.

Comment: Botje is absolutely right, not every `Actor` is a `Hero`. Did you intend to return a filtered list of all `Hero`s?

Comment: See also [this dup](/questions/25813435/what-exactly-are-covariant-return-types-in-c) and the fabulous C++ FAQ entry ["Is a parking-lot-of-Car a kind-of parking-lot-of-Vehicle?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#parkinglot-of-car-vs-vehicle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by Botje and churill, you cannot ensure that every `Actor` is `Hero`. So it doesn't make sense to do `getActor` with forced type of `T`. You can either get all `Actor`s and then filter outside manager, or `getFilteredActor` by type.

Below is a compile-able example:

```cpp
class Actor
{
public:
    virtual ~Actor() {};
};

class Hero : public Actor
{
public:
    virtual ~Hero() {};
};

class NonHero : public Actor
{
public:
    virtual ~NonHero() {};
};

class ActorManager
{
    ActorManager() {};
public:
    static ActorManager& instance()
    {
        static ActorManager actor_mgr;
        return actor_mgr;
    }

    void addActor(Actor* actor)
    {
        m_actors.push_back(unique_ptr<Actor>(actor));
    }

    const vector<unique_ptr<Actor>>& getActors() const
    {
        return m_actors;
    }

    template<typename T>
    vector<unique_ptr<T>> getFilteredActors() const
    {
        vector<unique_ptr<T>> filteredActor;
        for (auto& actor : m_actors) {
            T* casted = dynamic_cast<T*>(actor.get());
            if (casted != nullptr)
                filteredActor.push_back(unique_ptr<T>(casted));
        }

        return filteredActor;
    }

private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Actor>> m_actors;
};





int main()
{

    ActorManager& actor_mgr = ActorManager::instance();

    actor_mgr.addActor(new Hero());
    actor_mgr.addActor(new Hero());
    actor_mgr.addActor(new NonHero());

    for (const unique_ptr<Actor>& actor : ActorManager::instance().getActors())
    {
        // do something for general actor

        if (dynamic_cast<Hero*>(actor.get()) != nullptr)
        {
            // do something for hero specific
        }

        if (dynamic_cast<NonHero*>(actor.get()) != nullptr)
        {
            // do something for nonhero specific
        }
    }

    vector<unique_ptr<Hero>> heros = ActorManager::instance().getFilteredActors<Hero>();

}
```

Some notes:

- `static_cast` cannot downcast object of base class to object of derived class. You need to use `dynamic_cast` which only takes raw pointer (but not object itself) to cast `Actor` to `Hero`.
- not sure if you have defined at least one virtual function in `Actor` and `Hero`, if not, they won't have polymorphism.
- Since you are using `unique_ptr` which doesn't allow copy, so need to recreate from raw pointer retrieved from `get()` when put/get into manager. Maybe `shared_ptr` is more proper here.

Comment: `getFilteredActors` is unsafe, since vector returned by it doubles ownership over `std::unique_ptr`. Once this vector is destructed, all actors managed by it will get deallocated, `Hero` elements of `ActorManager::instance()::m_actors` will get deallocated. You should rather return vector of non-owning references, e.g. `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Hero>>`

Comment: Thanks @R2RT. I didn't realised this problem.